# How to make drop-down, which is open on mouse over(without click)?

Tags: drop-down-menu, hover

I'm trying to make drop-down, which is open on mouse over (without click).
Here is an example: http://aggatashop.com/index.php?route=common/home (Drop-downs are nearly to search form)
How to make 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to fire the click event on the mouseover event

```
$(dropdown).hover(function(){ $(this).click(); });
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks for answer.
I don't understand a lot of jquery, so please help.
Here is the code:


<div class="dropdown_bck">
<select class="dropdown" style="opacity:0;">      <option>test</option>
<option>test2</option>
</select>
<span></span>
</div>